# Postman returns the variable name and not value

Tags: reactjs, postman

I have a little problem and I can't seem to find a good answer to my question. So, I have a global Variable in Postman which saves an ID that I my Client needs.

I thought I'd use the following request: [https://postman-echo.com/get?{{myvariable}}](https://postman-echo.com/get?%7B%7Bmyvariable%7D%7D)

When I'm sending this request through Postman, the response looks good:

```
"args": {
    "var": "8373b870-9bd0-4e47-b296-035e155e584d"
},
```

But when I send this request throught my frontend, the response is not the UUID but just like this:

```
"args": {
    "var": {{myvariable}}
},
```

How can I get the Value of the variable on not the name?
I logged the full response so I can check if the value isn't stored somewhere, but it wasn't.

This is how I'm using the Endpoint from my Frontend:

```
axios.get('https://postman-echo.com/get?var={{myvariable}}')
        .then(response => {
            console.log("Response: " + JSON.stringify(response.data))
        })
```

So I'm just doing a simple GET Request with a response.

Comment: This looks like a query param, so I want to ask whether the {{var}} is the name of the variable or the actual variable. In that case it might look something like https://postman-echo.com/get?var={{myvariable}}

Comment: @AaqibBashir sorry I have been trying different things. The API Request URL should look like this: https://postman-echo.com/get?var={{myvariable}}.
"myvariable" is the name of the global variable where the ID ist stored.

Comment: So, Did it work?

Comment: @AaqibBashir no unfortunately not. The Response still just returns the name of the variable and not the value of the variable.

Comment: Is it working perfectly when you call the endpoint from the postman? Can you show how you're using the endpoint on your frontend? The problem is likely with you sending the data as a string rather than appending the variable to the url. You might have to append the {{myvariable}} to the url with + operator. That's a wild guess though!

Comment: @AaqibBashir I just edited my Post and added a snipped on how I'm using it in the Frontend. And when I'm calling it from Postman, it returns a Body looking like this:
"var": "8373b870-9bd0-4e47-b296-035e155e584d"
So the ID is getting returned but when I call it from my frontend it looks like this:
"var": {{myvariable}}

Comment: axios.get("https://postman-echo.com/get?var=" + "myvariable").then(response => {
            console.log("Response: " + JSON.stringify(response.data))
        })
create a var myvariable and store your uuid "8373b870-9bd0-4e47-b296-035e155e584d" in it
Kindly try this!

Comment: @AaqibBashir I'm really thankful for your help. But this didn't work.
"var" is the name of the variable that's been created and {{myvariable}} is the value of the global variable which is the assigned to the created variable var.
But somehow when sending back the Body as Response, the var value isn't the UUID anymore, but just the Name of the Global Variable

Comment: Try putting ${myvariable} maybe. I tested it with one of my endpoints